# Created nodes don't appear to be added to the neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I’ve created a couple of nodes in a neo4j database from within a groovy app, but when I connect to the database using the shell client they don’t appear to be there.

The database I’m creating is that described in http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html:

```
def graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("/tmp/foo.db");

Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()
def firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, ");
def secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");

tx.success();

System.err.print(firstNode.getProperty("message"));
System.err.print(relationship.getProperty("message"));
System.err.print(secondNode.getProperty("message"));

graphDb.shutdown()
```

After running the app, I can see that the database has been created on the filesystem, however when I connect from the shell client, it appears that there are no nodes in the database:

```
$ ./neo4j-community-2.1.5/bin/neo4j-shell -path /tmp/foo.db/ -v
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (m) return m;
+---+
| m |
+---+
+---+
0 row
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same version of neo4j for both?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I was using an earlier version in the groovy code, but then the shell client complained that it wouldn't open an older database.

Comment: I see no reason on why it shouldn't work :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I was wondering whether I needed to do anything else to make the database flush.  Also, it appears to take many seconds for the shutdown() to run... which seems strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close the transaction. `tx.success()` just marks the transaction as being successful but won't commit it. For finishing a transaction use `tx.close()`. Best practice is to use try-with-resources blocks when doing Java - this cares about calling `close()` automatically.

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = ...;
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) { 
    // do stuff
    tx.success();  
}
```

Since your code has a `def` I assume you're using groovy, which does not support try-with-resources. Hence the code looks like:

```
def graphDb = ....
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()
try {
    // do stuff e.g. create nodes
    tx.success()
} finally {
    tx.close()
}
```

Comment: there it is :) School boy error :) The example in http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html doesn't have the finally block.

Comment: Ah, ok. Try with resources is a java pattern that I'm not familiar with (my java foo is old(er) than it ought to be!)

Comment: try-with-resources has been added in Java 7.